# (DLLImport)Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, c++, interop, dllimport

I am trying to import a function from a C Code dll.

the function is

```
 bool AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(ESCORE_LCDBR_CONTROL Ctrl)
```

there is a enum in the c code

```
typedef enum
{
   ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_UP,
ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_DOWN
} ESCORE_LCDBR_CONTROL_TYPE;
```

I am trying to call it in Visual studio 2013 in a windows form application using C# with the following code -->

```
public enum EWestern { ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_UP = 0, ESCORE_LCDBTCTL_DOWN = 1 };

    [DllImport("AsrCore.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool AsrLibSetLcdBacklight([In]EWestern e);
```

and calling this function with a button click

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {
      if (AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(EWestern.ESCORE_LCDBTCTL_DOWN))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("backlight Decreased", "Test");
        }
    }
```

When I run the code I get an error about the SystemAccessViolation.

Please let me know what is the issue here, Am i doing it right ? is the syntax good ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your exported function is declared `CDECL` and not `STDCALL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve the Issue is to make sure that I was using the 64bit platform for my application and running the Application as a administrator.